# How to order posts from json array using javascript For In, or Object.keys loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to know how I can order posts by an object inside an arrary of posts from a json feed url, using for in or object.keys loop. this is an example of my json feed of a 3 posts :

```
{
    "entry":[
         {
            "id": 1,
            "thumbnail": "/images/1.jpg",
            "title": "This is a Title 1",
            "time": "13, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 5
        },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "thumbnail": "/images/2.jpg",
            "title": "This is Post Title 2",
            "time": "14, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 0
        },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "thumbnail": "/images/3.jpg",
            "title": "This is Post Title 3",
            "time": "15, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see there is an object "**comCount**" is mean the number of comments of entries, what I really need is to order my posts by most discussed!

This is my code but is just give me the order by default :

```
$(function () {

    var $mostDiscussed = $('.most-discussed');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/json/feeds/api.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var htmlcode= '<ul>';
            var feedcode = '';
            for (var i=0; i<data.entry.length; i++) {
                var id = data.entry[i].id,
                    title = data.entry[i].title,
                    thumbnail = data.entry[i].thumbnail,
                    summary = data.entry[i].summary;
                    time = data.entry[i].time,
                    count = data.entry[i].comCount,
                    thumb = '<img width="100%" src="' + thumbnail + '" title="' + title + '" alt=" ' + title + '" />';
                feedcode += '<li id="' + id + '" class="post">' + thumb + '<h3>' + title + '</h3><ul><li class="meta-time">' + time + '</li><li class="meta-comments">' + count + ' Comments</li></ul><p>' + summary + '<p></li>';
            }
            feedcode += '</ul>';
            htmlcode += feedcode;
            $mostDiscussed.html(htmlcode);
        }
    });

})
```

The Html code is just a div :

```
<div class="most-discussed"></div>
```

I really need to know how I can sort by an object value of an array if is possible! thanks in advance!

> Sorry guys I forget to explain something I need this order to be on
>   the front end not on the json file! because I need to create a blogger
>   plugin for Most Discussed Posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript `sort()` function with custom comparator function to sort on the basis of the object value on the array of objects like. For frontend, just sort and then loop over the data;

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.comCount > b.comCount)
    return -1;
  if (a.comCount < b.comCount)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  var data = [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "thumbnail": "/images/1.jpg",
            "title": "This is a Title 1",
            "time": "13, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "thumbnail": "/images/3.jpg",
            "title": "This is Post Title 3",
            "time": "15, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 10
        },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "thumbnail": "/images/2.jpg",
            "title": "This is Post Title 2",
            "time": "14, Oct 2016",
            "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            "comCount": 0
        }
         
    ]

function compare(a,b) {
  return  (b.comCount- a.comCount)
   
}

data.sort(compare);

        var htmlcode= '<ul>';
        var feedcode = '';
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var id = data[i].id,
                title = data[i].title,
                thumbnail = data[i].thumbnail,
                summary = data[i].summary;
                time = data[i].time,
                count = data[i].comCount,
                thumb = '<img width="100%" src="' + thumbnail + '" title="' + title + '" alt=" ' + title + '" />';
            feedcode += '<li id="' + id + '" class="post">' + thumb + '<h3>' + title + '</h3><ul><li class="meta-time">' + time + '</li><li class="meta-comments">' + count + ' Comments</li></ul><p>' + summary + '<p></li>';
        }
        feedcode += '</ul>';
        htmlcode += feedcode;
        $('.most-discussed').html(htmlcode);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="most-discussed"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I think I forget to explain something! I need this sort of posts on the front-end not on the json file! for example the posts sorted like that : id 1 - id 2 - id 3 but what I need to get sorted but the most commented so should be id 3 - id 1 - id 2 but on the front end :)

Comment: @Uikithemes You can just sort the data first and then append the data to div as you are doing now

Comment: but the big problem as the developers of blogger can't edit the json feed api, I just make an json array to explain my case! this is my full code on [link](https://jsfiddle.net/infinyteam/jb0cwdjj/) recenty jsfiddle block the external json URLs so you can copy paste the code to any other edito to see the result!

Comment: Thank you this is really good but just one thing I need to order by the most commented by decrement from 10 to 0?

Comment: @Uikithemes edited the code for that. Just a change in the compare function

Comment: I really thank you so much, is working fine with me bro! thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi again, this is working fine with me on the example but no on my own plugin that I would like to create :( see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infinyteam/z1jn41rm/2/) I've added your code between a comment, please can you find a solution?

Comment: So sorry, is working fine I missed to change the object, see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infinyteam/z1jn41rm/4/) is really work, thank you so much, Sorry For Disturb!

Answer (score 3):

You could just sort the feed object and then iterate.

```js
function SortData() {
  var feed = {
    "entry": [{
      "id": 1,
      "thumbnail": "/images/1.jpg",
      "title": "This is a Title 1",
      "time": "13, Oct 2016",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "comCount": 5
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "thumbnail": "/images/2.jpg",
      "title": "This is Post Title 2",
      "time": "14, Oct 2016",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "comCount": 0
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "thumbnail": "/images/3.jpg",
      "title": "This is Post Title 3",
      "time": "15, Oct 2016",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "comCount": 10
    }]
  };

  let sortedData = feed.entry.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj2.comCount - obj1.comCount
  });

  return {
    entry: sortedData
  };
}
$(function() {

  var $mostDiscussed = $('.most-discussed');
  var data = SortData();



  var htmlcode = '<ul>';
  var feedcode = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.entry.length; i++) {
    var id = data.entry[i].id,
      title = data.entry[i].title,
      thumbnail = data.entry[i].thumbnail,
      summary = data.entry[i].summary;
    time = data.entry[i].time,
      count = data.entry[i].comCount,
      thumb = '<img width="100%" src="' + thumbnail + '" title="' + title + '" alt=" ' + title + '" />';
    feedcode += '<li id="' + id + '" class="post">' + thumb + '<h3>' + title + '</h3><ul><li class="meta-time">' + time + '</li><li class="meta-comments">' + count + ' Comments</li></ul><p>' + summary + '<p></li>';
  }

  feedcode += '</ul>';
  htmlcode += feedcode;
  $mostDiscussed.html(htmlcode);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="most-discussed">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I think I forget to explain something! I need this sort of posts on the front-end not on the json file! for example the posts sorted like that : id 1 - id 2 - id 3 but what I need to get sorted but the most commented so should be id 3 - id 1 - id 2 but on the front end :)

Comment: Updated the snippet for better clarity. once the ajax call is made, you could sort the date and iterate on it, instead of iterating directly on the returned data.

Comment: Yes I update the snippet :), my needed goal is to create a Most Discussed Posts, so I need to order using "comCount" object then the default sort! the result sort is should be : the thrid post (10 comments) > the first post(5 comments) > the second post(0 comments). do you get it now?

Comment: I just refresh the page, and this is what I'm really looking for, Thank you so much for your help, and thanks to others too :)

Comment: Hi again, how I can use this code on this json feed url [link](http://sunrisesunset-theme.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&orderby=published&max-results=10) as I said I just create an example of json array to explain what I need, but I get data from the json feed url above so how I can sort by comments?

Comment: you can have your ajax code as is. in success callback call SortData(data) and operate on the returned data.

Comment: This is really my full code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infinyteam/z1jn41rm/1/) as you see the posts not sorted by most commented please can you edit the code and update it?

Comment: Looks good here, with the changes I did. https://jsfiddle.net/z1jn41rm/3/

Comment: Thank you so much bro your code is clean and short! are you know how I can get posts by author? this is the author object data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t